# VBA Variable not defined when calling Method with Object

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I develop the first time using VBA (Was using vb.net etc. before).
I always get the error

> Variable is not defined

when running the code.
On calling the method `writeHeaders` the program always quits.

Some help would be highly appreciated, this thing drives me nuts atm.

```
Option Explicit

Sub exportToAPplus()

    Dim applusImport As Workbook
    Set applusImport = createFile
    writeHeaders applusImport
End Sub

Function createFile() As Workbook

    Dim dateiName As String
    dateiName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename()
    If dateiName <> "Falsch" And dateiName <> "False" Then
        Dim applusImport As Workbook
        dateiName = dateiName + "xlsx"
        Set applusImport = Workbooks.Add
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        applusImport.SaveAs dateiName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Set createFile = applusImport
    Else
        MsgBox ("Sie haben keinen Dateinamen ausgewählt, es wurde nichts 
        gespeichert.")
    End If

End Function

Sub writeHeaders(applusImport As Workbook)
    Dim headers() As Variant
    headers() = Array("DATUM", "AUFTRAG", "PERSONAL", "KSTR", "INNENAUFTRAG", "POSITION", "AG", "KAPAST", "MASCHINENGRUPPE", "START", "ENDE", "DAUER", "BESCHREIBUNG")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = LBound(headers()) To UBound(headers()) Step 1
        .Cells(1, 1 + i).Value = headers(i)
    Next i
    applusImport.Save
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have errors please always include in which **line** you get the error. • The error *"Variable is not defined"* here means that your variable `i` is not declared. You must declare it and specify its type eg. `Dim i As Long` before you can use `i`.

Comment: Reason is your option explicit, which demands each variable to be declared. If you omit option explicit, which I do not recommend, the variable i would automatically be dimensioned as variant

Comment: Btw you don't need a loop to write your headers out. You can do in one line with Cells(1, 1).Resize(1,UBound(headers) + 1) = headers

Answer (score 2):

The error

> "Variable is not defined"

means that you used a variable without defining it.

The variable you didn't declare yet in `writeHeaders` is the variable `i`. 
You must declare it and specify its type before you can use `i`:

```
Dim i As Long 
For i = LBound(headers()) To UBound(headers()) Step 1
```

Note that this kind of error occurs because you use `Option Explicit` to force variable declaration (which is highly recommended to do). For more information see: [Excel Easy: Option Explicit](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)

Answer (score 1):

Before running the project, go to `Debug>Compile Project` and it would tell you which variable is not declared:

[image]

This works only, if you have written `Option Explicit` on the top of the Module/Class/Object (but you have it).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Peh. You need to declare i in For Loops in VBA.